# selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar running on server, how to get started?

Tags: selenium

I downloaded and excuted via java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0rc2.jar....

and selenium remote control is running....

basically, two other people and myself need to run firefox browser tests of our web application.

how can 3 people run multiple parallel tests on the selenium rc currently running? Do I need to define new port for each test (firefox instances)? what about xvnc?

is Selenium Grid a more suitable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a chance of more people using the selenium instance, its better you go for Selenium-Grid. Selenium grid will ensure that you don't have to worry about allocation of RCs to different tests.

Start one hub and 3 remote controls (RCs) in the grid. All 3 of you can then point to same hubURL in the command which you use to start the selenium session (would be something like `new DefaultSelenium("URL",port,***)` Hub will allocate the RCs as and when new request comes in.

If you are using Grid 2 please refer the [selenium wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) for quick start instructions.

Note:- The number of tests that can be run in parallel depends on the number of remote controls connected to the hub. So 3 Remote controls means only 3 tests can be run in parallel. You need to increase the number of remote controls as required.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest if you are looking for parallelism I wouldn't look at Grid 1, Grid 2 only just released may help you. On Grid 1 you can only have 1 RC assigned for each node.

Selenium RC can take as many connections as you want to throw at it. You will run out of memory and usable CPU before RC starts rejecting requests.

For simplicity I would have one Selenium RC and then get everyone using that. That way if someone needs to run tests they just run it and let the test run happily